# Install a lot of fonts at once

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I have a collection of free fonts that I want to install on my Mac. But it is too tedious to double click every one of them and then click "Install font". Is there a quick way to do this? Like a certain context menu to "install all the fonts selected" or a terminal command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your OS X version, it should be possible to open Font Book and then drag the entire collection of fonts you wish to install from Finder onto the Font Book window.

Answer (score 1):

While in Finder, hold option key and click on Go menu then choose Library. In Library, find Font folder, drag and drop the fonts into this folder. I keep my fonts organised into separate folders inside Font folder and the OS picks them up.

Comment: Putting such free fonts in a separate folder is extremely wise, since it is possible some of them will be junk and corrupt your display at some point, so you will want to be able to locate them and remove them.